# Separate downvote and upvote tallies

Tags: feature-request, privileges, vote-count

As I have observed there is some frustration associated with down votes. Downvotes and upvotes however serve a useful purpose, in most cases readers can get to the information they want faster. However I point out that there is a flaw with this system in that common knowledge can instead be common misconception.

As such I suggest splitting downvote tallies and upvote tallies. Specialist users can then feel better about an answer with downvotes because they also received upvotes.

An alternative or additional feature suggestion is for upvotes and downvotes to be weighted by user estimated expertise or activity.

Comment: [This already exists, users simply require 1k reputation to see the vote split.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Comment: @Servy Why do you need 1k?

Comment: Anecdotal evidence from Meta threads suggests that it is not the specialists who feel strongly about downvotes.

Comment: @duplode That would be a generalization of the supposed specialists in those Meta threads. Specialist here is anyone who doesn't share the general misconception.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. I recently posted a feature request because I had no idea it was awarded at 1k rep. I think most people are probably in the same boat, they want it, but don't want to use the site long enough to get that 1k rep without it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This already exists, but is a privilege.

As part of the [established user privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) (1000 rep on Stack Overflow), one can click on the score to see the split between upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: How unfortunate for the majority.

Comment: @user3345413 You can install a userscript that gives you the option without 1K rep: http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

Comment: @user000001: Can you help me about how to install the script?

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 it's available as an extension for chrome

Comment: @user000001: Does it have Safari version? I don't know how to install it...

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 I have no idea, never used Safari

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if there is a question in your original post, but I would like to express solidarity that seeing the number of upvotes and downvotes on a particular question or answer would be something that should be given to every, or nearly every user. For this reason 1,000 is too high, and something like 100 would be more appropriate.

Also I would like to echo your thoughts that common knowledge can instead be common misconception. My most down voted answers by far have been the ones where I tried to clear up common misconceptions, as expressed by the other answers already receiving up votes for the question.

Comment: There's a couple of related discussions on the Main Meta as well here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97892/rep-for-view-vote-count-privilege-should-be-lower-on-meta and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77893/is-the-reputation-requirement-for-showing-total-upvote-and-downvote-counts-very

Comment: @BSMP Yes, those are good. I think they both get at the heart of the problem, that the difficulty of getting 1000k on the main site != 1000k on any other site.